# New single page for handling result from payment gateway in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I currently working on project with Joomla. Now develop payment gateway for Virtuemart. All is good. But payment gateway need notification URI (for send status of transaction after payment process). So, how create single page for handle result from payment gateway?

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom payment plugin and component that handles the payment notification requests issued by payment gateway. For Virtuemart should be available for most common gateway.

If you need joomla customization, consultancy or expertise team visits our site http://storejoomla.org